# Remove excess categories in layer styling

Tags: qgis, layers, style

I am working on a small project area and have downloaded a province-wide geological dataset.  The dataset comes with a legend/layer file but it is a massive dataset (35424 polygons) with 2300 legend categories.  To make it more manageable I have made a duplicate file which i have cropped down to my project area (575 polygons).  I want to use the provincial legend but when i load the cropped file with the provincial legend, it still loads up  all 2300 unique legend entries, even though many have no associated polygons.

Is there an simple and quick way to delete all categories which have no associated polygon?

Image 1: Image of the layer styling panel - I cannot display the feature count on this panel, making it difficult to easily delete those entries with 0 corresponding polygons.

Image 2: layer panel displaying just a few of the many entries with no associated polygon (here I can see the feature count)

[image: Image 1: Image of the layer styling panel - I cannot display the feature count on this panel, making it difficult to easily delete those entries with 0 corresponding polygons.]

[image: Image 2: layer panel displaying just a few of the many entries with no associated polygon (here I can see the feature count)]

Comment: have you tried deleting all categories  (delete all button), then reclassifying on the same value by clicking the classify button?